# JavaScript/TypeScript equilavant of PHP's magic ::class constant

Tags: javascript, typescript

**PHP** has some build-in *magic constants*, one of which is `::class`. Since I am building more and more applications with NodeJS + TypeScript I wondered what the *JavaScript/TypeScript* equivalent is of the following *PHP code*

```
$callable = array( Foo::class, 'method' );

call_user_func( $callable );
```

I tried using the following, but that is obviously not a correct *array value*

```
const callable = [Foo.constructor.name, 'method']
```

And how can I then call the *method*?

Comment: `method = Foo.prototype.method`. then you can `method(param1, param2)` or `method.call(someObject, param1, param2)`

Comment: Given it's a static method - just do `Foo['method']()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP symbols are not values in the same way they are in JS. We can't pass around classes in PHP, only their names. This works in PHP because class names are globally unique (namespace included).

In Javascript classes are 'first class', and disconnected from their name. They are not globally unique. So the premise doesn't make *that much* sense to me. You shouldn't pass around just the name, because with the name alone you cannot figure out what class it *was*.

However, here are some things that resemble what you need.

If we look at the `[class, staticMethod]` structure as a single value that you want to be able to call, then the easiest is to use:

```
const callable = Foo.method;

// callable
callable();
```

This is so natural in Javascript. In PHP the array syntax for referencing things that are callable is a bit of a hack, so it's not really the model you'll want to replicate.

If, for some reason, you want to have a value that has the method name and a reference to it's class, you don't need to do this by name (which aren't globally unique), do it by reference.

```
const callable = [Foo, 'method'];

// Call it:
callable[0][callable[1]]();
```

It's tempting going into a new language to re-use the patterns that you are used to from your old one; but Javascript model is significantly different. Whatever you're *actually* trying to achieve probably has a solution that's more natural to JS.